# SPLUNK: How can I count events by location with a list of SERVERNAME's?

Tags: count, location, splunk

Our splunk implementation has SERVERNAME as a preset field, and there are servers in different locations, but there is no location field.  How can I count errors by location?
I envision something like this but cannot find a way to implement:

```
index=some_index "some search criteria"
| eval PODNAME="ONTARIO" if SERVERNAME IN ({list of servernames})
| eval PODNAME="GEORGIA" if SERVERNAME IN ({list of servernames})
| timechart span=30min count by PODNAME
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Here's how to do that in SPL.

```
index=some_index "some search criteria"
| eval PODNAME=case(in(SERVERNAME, {list of servernames}), "ONTARIO",
                    in(SERVERNAME, {list of servernames}), "GEORGIA",
                    1==1, "unknown" )
| timechart span=30min count by PODNAME
```

There's a better way, though, since the above doesn't scale well with many locations and may become hard to maintain if the code is used in many places.  Use a lookup table.

Create a CSV file with SERVERNAME and PODNAME columns then use the lookup to map server name to location.

```
index=some_index "some search criteria"
| lookup serverlocation.csv SERVERNAME OUTPUT PODNAME
| timechart span=30min count by PODNAME
```

Comment: the servernames are case sensitive and must be in quotes.